# Polymorphism and subtypes for Flow arrays

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I can't get polymorphic subtypes to work in arrays with Flow generics as I would in another language like Java.

Consider the following.

```
interface Person {
    name:string;
}

class Employee implements Person {
    name:string;
    badge:string;
}

interface Workplace {
    people:Array<Person>;
}

class MyOffice implements Workplace {
    people:Array<Employee>;  // ERROR: Incompatible with Workplace.people
}
```

This would fail in Java as well; but Java has a way to implement this correctly by indicating the  `people` array in `Workplace` would contain subtypes of `Person`.

```
interface Workplace {
    people:Array<? extends Person>; // PSUEDO CODE: This is how Java supports subtypes
}
```

I have not been able to find a comparable mechanism in Flow. Flow discusses variance here: https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/variance/#toc-covariance and https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/depth-subtyping/

Which suggests that the following should work.

```
interface Workplace {
    people:Array<+Person>;
}
```

But this syntax fails.

Is there a way in Flow to declare an Array covariant type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variance in Flow takes some getting used to. The core thing, as you've mentioned, is that these two operations would be invalid if

```
interface Workplace {
    people:Array<Person>;
}
```

were allowed as-is:

```
var workplace: Workplace = new MyOffice();

// Not an `Employee`, can't allow adding to array
workplace.people.push(new SomeOtherPersonImpl()); 

// Not an `Employee`, can't allow replacing array.
workplace.people = [new SomeOtherPersonImpl()];
```

to get both of these properties, we need to

1. Make the `people` array read-only ([$ReadOnlyArray](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/arrays/#toc-readonlyarray)).
2. Make the `people` *property* read-only. (The `+` you mentioned)

Combining these, you end up with:

```
interface Workplace {
    +people: $ReadOnlyArray<Person>;
}
```

([Flow Try Example](https://flow.org/try/#0JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyxyIcAthAFzIZhSgDmA3AQL4EEIA2cGGyAKLkADtywBPCCmCjuESuAHoo2XIRKkK1WvSatNAIzgATRjroMQLdp1CRYiFAHUsUANZin+IiQDUIhBYYtQAJABKEKYA8iDcEgCCUFBwEgA8KmoAfKwcXLz8yACyEtEwMMBIyLIhimACrh5eVRokgcHyNEkp6cJiktI57EA))

Comment: Thanks, very nice answer